# System of second order differential equations

Tags: python, scipy, differential-equations

I need to visualize the pendulum connected to oscillator. So I have system of second order differential equations:

```
(m1 + m2)*x1'' + m2*l*(x2''*cos(x2) - x2'*x2'*sin(x2)) + c*q1 = 0

x1''*cos(x2) - x1'*x2'*sin(x2) + l*x2'' + x1'*x2'*x2'*sin(x2) + g*x2'*sin(x2) = 0

m1 - mass of oscillator
m2 - mass of pendulum

l - length of pendulum
c - spring rate
g = 9.8

x1 - start position of oscillator
x2 - angle of pendulum
```

I was trying to find library for python to solve differential equations. I found scipy. So I needed to make `y1=x1'` and `y2 = x2'`, and then express `y1'` and `y2'` for this library.

```
from math import cos, sin, pi

def vectorfield(w,p):
    q1, y1, q2, y2 = w
    m1, m2, c, l, g = p

    f = [y1,
         (-m2*l*(c*q1*cos(q2)/(m1+m2) - m2*l*y2*y2*sin(q2)*cos(q2)/(m1+m2) + y1*y2*sin(q2)
          - y1*y2*y2*sin(q2) - g*y2*sin(q2)) / (l - m2*l*cos(q2)*cos(q2)/(m1+m2))*cos(q2)
          + m2*l*y2*y2*sin(q2) - c*q1) / (m1 + m2),
         y2,
         (c*q1*cos(q2)/(m1+m2) - m2*l*y2*y2*sin(q2)*cos(q2)/(m1+m2) + y1*y2*sin(q2)
          - y1*y2*y2*sin(q2) - g*y2*sin(q2)) / (l - m2*l*cos(q2)*cos(q2)/(m1+m2))
         ]
    return f

def customCos(val):
    return cos(pi*val/180)

def customSin(val):
    return sin(pi*val/180)
```

And then put this function in `odeint`

```
m1 = 1.0
m2 = 0.5
# Spring constants
c = 200.0
l = 0.1
g = 9.8

# Initial conditions
# x1 and x2 are the initial displacements; y1 and y2 are the initial velocities
q1 = 1.0
y1 = 0.0
q2 = 0.5
y2 = 0.0

stoptime = 10.0
numpoints = 20

t = [stoptime * float(i) / (numpoints - 1) for i in range(numpoints)]

# Pack up the parameters and initial conditions:
p = [m1, m2, c, l, g]
w0 = [q1, y1, q2, y2]

# Call the ODE solver.
wsol = odeint(vectorfield, w0, t, args=(p,))
```

But the result look really wrong. So are my calculations wrong or I use this library in a wrong way?

Comment: Try `def vectorfield(w, t, p):`. Even if you do not have a time-dependency, the integrator likely needs it.

Comment: Your initial equations (apart from `q1` being `x1`) look not correct, especially the third degree derivative term in the second equation. The spring-cart-pendulum equations can be readily found in several places, for instance in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2026118/approximating-spring-cart-pendulum-system

Comment: Note that in the Euler-Lagrange equations `d/dt ( dL/d(q') ) = dL/dq` there is no additional time derivative on the right side.